# Parsing text for table of contents

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

```
def table_of_contents(text):
    i = 0
    toc = []
    for chapter in range(1,60):
        pattern = re.compile(r'(\S+ )?(' + str(chapter) + ')( \S+)?', re.I)
        m = pattern.search(text[i:])
        if m is not None:
            toc.append(m.start())
            i = m.start()
        else:
            break
    return toc
```

This function doesn't do what I want even thought I think it should.  I've tried debugging it but re seems to be opaque to the pdb.  The problem is toc should be strictly ascending, however, I'm getting results like

```
toc = [513, 435, 378, 486, 650, 789, 942]
```

What is happening?

Why is search jumping backward when text[i:] should only be increasing?

Why doesn't pattern and m show up in pdb?

Comment: You defined the context  as optional substrings. You might try setting word boundaries at least, try `r'\b' + str(chapter) + r'\b'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot. re.search(text[i:]) is returning m.start() from 0 instead of i

```
def table_of_contents(text):
    i = 0
    toc = []
    for chapter in range(1,60):
        pattern = re.compile(r'(\S+ )?(' + str(chapter) + ')( \S+)?', re.I)
        m = pattern.search(text[i:])
        if m is not None:
            toc.append(m.start() + i)
            i += m.start()
    else:
        break
return toc
```